# Accepting lambda expressions as input from users in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using `tkinter` to create an interface for a preprocessing script that would accept user inputs and filter a `pandas` dataframe accordingly. The code snippet below accepts a simple function from the user, and prints the result.

Code:-

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()


entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=50)
entry1.pack()


def demo_func(f):
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "y": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
    return tmp.apply(f, axis=1)


def myclick():
    text = entry1.get()
    func = eval(f"lambda x: {text}")
    mylabel = tk.Label(root, text=demo_func(func))
    mylabel.pack()


mybutton = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", command=myclick)
mybutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Result :-

[image]

I want to be able to enter expressions which will allow users to specify operations on particular columns, for example, `f'The new value of column x is {x["x"] ** 2}'`.

If I enter the expression in the entry box, I get the following error : -
[image]

Expected Result (obtained by hardcoding values):

[image]

Is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your code as copyable text, not as an image

Comment: I've added the code in the image as a copyable text in the question body

Comment: Python doesn't understand `The new value of column.....` You either need to only provide the expression or parse the text from the user to only contain the expression part.

Comment: I want the app to be able to pass the expression to the backend where the expression can be used inside the `apply` function. I want to figure out a way in which I can pass the user input like an f string

Comment: I don't think f-strings can be lazily evaluated. You could try regular string formatting.